# Decide what byte causes the zlib inflate decompression operation

Tags: python, zlib, compression, deflate, inflate

I got the following code which suppose to decompress a simple inflated data.

```
import zlib
print zlib.decompress(content)
```

It crashes with the following error

```
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back
```

I want to be able to log the index of the exact byte (the first one) that causes the decompression to fail... Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Make a decompressor object with `decompressobj`, and feed it a byte at a time with `decompress` until it fails with the error.